# jquery apply strike() method to object

Tags: javascript

I am able to getting the selected string value in the following way,

```
    if(!window.Kolich){
      Kolich = {};
    }
    Kolich.Selector = {};
    Kolich.Selector.getSelected = function(){
      var t = '';
      if(window.getSelection){       
        t = window.getSelection();      
      } 
      return t;
    }
    Kolich.Selector.mouseup = function(){
     var st = Kolich.Selector.getSelected();
  // alert(typeof(st)) //showing object
     var data = st.toString();
     data.strike();
    }
```

But i need to apply strike() method to the selected string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the `strike()` method, try using the [`DOM Range`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) `surroundContents()` method instead.

```
if(!window.Kolich){
  Kolich = {};
}

Kolich.Selector = {};
Kolich.Selector.getSelected = function(){
  var t = '';
  if(window.getSelection){       
    t = window.getSelection();      
  } 
  return t;
}

Kolich.Selector.mouseup = function(){
  var st = Kolich.Selector.getSelected();
  // alert(typeof(st)) //showing object
  //var data = st.toString();    
  var range = st.getRangeAt(0);    
  var strike = document.createElement("strike");    

  range.surroundContents(strike);    
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F8saX/